# How do I get my divs aligned next to each other?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the number "87" sit next to the words "total score"?

I want the number on the right and "total score" text on the left, but with "total score" written across two lines.

I've tried using various div structures, floats and display properties but can't get it working.

```html
<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;"><strong>Total<br>Score</strong>
  <div><span id="count" style="font-size: 2em;">87</span></div>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;">
  Rank #1 out of 321
</div>
```

Comment: `<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;">
 <span><strong>Total Score : <strong></span>
 <span id="count" style="font-size: 2em;">87</span>
</div>`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLxPvJ or https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrmNog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
div {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div > * {margin: 0 5px} /* adjust */

#count {font-size: 2em}
```

```html
<div>
  <strong>Total<br>Score</strong>
  <span id="count">87</span>
</div>

<div>Rank #1 out of 321</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `css` of `strong` and `div` after that

```html
<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;">

  <strong style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Total<br>Score</strong>
  
  <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"><span id="count" style="font-size: 2em;">87</span></div>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;">
  Rank #1 out of 321
</div>
```

Comment: No need to use `flex-box` to achieve this, i have tried to make simplest solution for you

Answer (score 0):

This will looks more good , please try this

```html
<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;">
  <strong style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Total Score : 
    <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;><span id="count" style="font-size: 2em;">87</span></div>
   </strong>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; padding: 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #eee; border-radius: 10px;">
  Rank #1 out of 321
</div>
```